# Hide button Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I´m trying to learn Xcode, and have a beginner question:
I want to hide a button when the app launches, and make it appear when another is pressed.

I have managed to hide/show labels using .isHidden, but when I try using that command on the button Swift wants to use (sender: any) and that doesn't go with .xxxx commands as far as I can understand.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of an error, because `.isHidden` should work

Comment: Are you writing software for macOS, iOS, tvOS, or watchOS?

Answer (score 2):

Drag UIButton from Object Library and then go to Attribute Inspector property of UIButton then you can select Hidden property from it and you will not able to see UIButton on screen

Answer (score 1):

Use this property:

```
yourButton.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the whole thing

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cmdButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cmdButton2: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       cmdButton2.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func cmdButton1Clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        cmdButton2.isHidden = false
    }
}
```